# How can I find the index of a substring when searching for multiple different matches?

Tags: python, list, substring

Good Afternoon, appreciate any help on this one.

I am trying to find the index of month text when searching a string in python. The goal is to remove the date at the end of some text `last_chars`.

So far I have the below code:

```
matches = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
if any(x in last_chars for x in matches):
    answer = answer[0:-12]
    
    print("Removing the Date")
```

I am trying to chop the date off the end but the problem is that sometimes it is not 12 characters due to the day value being either one or two digits. Example Jun 22, 1999 vs Jun 2, 1999.

I am trying to find the index of the match so I can use that to slice the string. It is assumed that there is only one match. I have tried the `find()` method but I can't seem to get it to work with this if statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

It's nice and easy with split.

I'm not sure what last_chars is, but check each month and pass the relevant one to "split" if it appears. Split returns a list - the first item [0] appears before the match.

```
last_chars = "some text Jun 22, 1999"
matches = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
for match in matches:
    if match in last_chars: results = last_chars.split(match)[0]
```

results will yield "some text "